# Declaração de tipo entre parênteses

Tags: c++, cast

Estou portando um aplicativo feito em c para C++ e encontrei a seguinte declaração de função:

```
set_funcao(0, (double)pow((double)2, 32) );
```

O que significa o tipo entre parênteses?

É o tipo de retorno adquirido no momento, ou seja, uma conversão?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso chama-se *casting*, você está mandando o valor seguinte se comportar como o tipo que está entre parênteses. Em alguns casos é só para instruir o compilador de como se comportar, em outros tem um conversão de formato do dado e portanto algum processamento.

Em casos de números o compilador já faz *castings* implícitos quando não há perda de dados, em outros a única forma é dizer que deseja o *casting* de forma explícita, que é o caso.

Neste seu exemplo o *casting* mais interno não é necessário, se tivesse usado `2.0` dava no mesmo, porque esse é claramente um número do tipo `double`, e é a forma preferida de fazer. Mas como há um *casting* implícito de `int` para `double` quando o parâmetro espera um `double`, podia ter usado apenas `2`, mesmo sem *casting* explícito, sem mais nada. O outro também não é necessário porque a função [`pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) retorna justamente um `double`. Então eu desconfiaria deste código que pegou porque ele faz coisas completamente desnecessárias. E eu nem usaria esta função, pra que usar uma função para uma coisa que você pode fazer a conta na mão de obter o valor de 2 elevado a 32 e usar direto? Se fosse um operador o compilador otimizaria e tudo ficaria tranquilo, mas a função não será otimizada, é um desperdício. Para C ou C++ isso costuma fazer diferença.

Comment: Obrigado ela resposta.
Este código é de um programa bem antigo de Software Livre feito em C. 
Estou estudando C++ tentando migrar ele, segundo o Livro do Bjarne.

Comment: Se quer aprender C++ aprenda C++, não use nada de C, são linguagens completamente diferentes.

Answer (score 6):

O tipo entre parênteses é uma operação de casting de tipos (ou conversão de tipos, se preferir).

Em C++ existem diferentes operações de casting de tipos:

**Conversão implicita**

Essa conversão acontece entre tipos primitivos compatíveis entre si.

```
short a=2000;
int b;
b=a;
```

**Conversão explicita**

C++ tem tipagem forte e por isso muitas conversões precisam ser declaradas explicitamente:

```
short a=2000;
int b;
b = (int) a;    // notação c-like
b = int (a);    // notação funcional
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
Ficou bem claro.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Sua dúvida já foi respondida, mas apenas para complementar, em C++ moderno você deve evitar C-Style Cast.

```
// Bad
int v = (int)std::pow(3, 2);

// Good
int v = static_cast<int>(std::pow(3, 2));
```